# Zero visitors a day? Broken statistics

Tags: bug, status-completed, statistics

I see this on the frontpage of UX:

[image: 0 visitors/day]

Do we really have 0 visitors a day? Or is there something wrong with the statistics? (Always lying :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably related to the rename from http://ui.stackexchange.com to http://ux.stackexchange.com and I expect the stat will start functioning again in a few more days.

But I'll check to be sure.

Comment: Working again, good to see :)

Answer (score 1):

Jeff is correct - it will take 7 days for google analytics to catch up with the name change.

Comment: Ah, that is too sad.. But ok, thanks for the info!